# How to deserialize json returned by IPGeoLocation API and Use it in .chtml View

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I'm trying to write a code where I get the data of a particular IP, I have used this API named Free IP GeoLocation API

https://rapidapi.com/jkosgei/api/free-ip-geolocation

i have tried making list of some of the data and tried to deserialize it but it returns nothing.

```
"{\n    \"ip\": \"72.255.29.148\",\n    \"is_eu\": false,\n    \"city\": \"Karachi\",\n    \"region\": \"Sindh\",\n    \"region_code\": \"SD\",\n    \"country_name\": \"Pakistan\",\n    \"country_code\": \"PK\",\n    \"continent_name\": \"Asia\",\n    \"continent_code\": \"AS\",\n    \"latitude\": 24.9043,\n    \"longitude\": 67.0817,\n    \"asn\": \"AS9541\",\n    \"organisation\": \"Cyber Internet Services (Pvt) Ltd.\",\n    \"postal\": \"12311\",\n    \"calling_code\": \"92\",\n    \"flag\": \"https://ipdata.co/flags/pk.png\",\n    \"emoji_flag\": \"\\ud83c\\uddf5\\ud83c\\uddf0\",\n    \"emoji_unicode\": \"U+1F1F5 U+1F1F0\",\n    \"languages\": [\n        {\n            \"name\": \"English\",\n            \"native\": \"English\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"name\": \"Urdu\",\n            \"native\": \"\\u0627\\u0631\\u062f\\u0648\",\n            \"rtl\": 1\n        }\n    ],\n    \"currency\": {\n        \"name\": \"Pakistani Rupee\",\n        \"code\": \"PKR\",\n        \"symbol\": \"PKRs\",\n        \"native\": \"\\u20a8\",\n        \"plural\": \"Pakistani rupees\"\n    },\n    \"time_zone\": {\n        \"name\": \"Asia/Karachi\",\n        \"abbr\": \"PKT\",\n        \"offset\": \"+0500\",\n        \"is_dst\": false,\n        \"current_time\": \"2019-08-31T11:03:28.948199+05:00\"\n    },\n    \"threat\": {\n        \"is_tor\": false,\n        \"is_proxy\": false,\n        \"is_anonymous\": false,\n        \"is_known_attacker\": false,\n        \"is_known_abuser\": false,\n        \"is_threat\": false,\n        \"is_bogon\": false\n    },\n    \"count\": \"11\"\n}"
```

im getting null value of deserializing this, here's my api call and all of the controller code

```
var client = new RestClient("https://jkosgei-free-ip-geolocation-v1.p.rapidapi.com/72.255.29.148?api-key=66b8727d81306cd56a5300b77ee8d4699c85d8a87ff91d42cb62f10e");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "jkosgei-free-ip-geolocation-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
            request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "0fd0540211msh6eb28a39b114e5ap116f3fjsn60c6c9371c26");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var CachedData = response.Content;
            string json = CachedData.ToString();
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IPList>(json);
            return View(deserialized.IPData);
```

here are both of the models that i have used

```
public class IPList
    {
        public IEnumerable<IP> IPData { get; set; }
    }
    public class IP
    {
        public int ip { get; set; }
        public int is_eu { get; set; }
        public int city { get; set; }
        public int region { get; set; }
        public int region_code { get; set; }
        public int country_name { get; set; }
        public int country_code { get; set; }
        public int continent_name { get; set; }
        public int continent_code { get; set; }
        public int latitude { get; set; }
        public int longitude { get; set; }
        public int asn { get; set; }
        public int organisation { get; set; }
        public int postal { get; set; }
        public int calling_code { get; set; }
        public int flag { get; set; }
        public int emoji_flag { get; set; }
        public int emoji_unicode { get; set; }
        public int currency { get; set; }
    }
```

when i run the program it returns null in variable deserialized and deserialized.IPData

i am new to deserializing so please dont judge me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `IP` class which doesn't have correct structure.
The correct structure for the json you've provided is this:

```
public class Language
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string native { get; set; }
    public int? rtl { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string native { get; set; }
    public string plural { get; set; }
}

public class TimeZone
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string abbr { get; set; }
    public string offset { get; set; }
    public bool is_dst { get; set; }
    public DateTime current_time { get; set; }
}

public class Threat
{
    public bool is_tor { get; set; }
    public bool is_proxy { get; set; }
    public bool is_anonymous { get; set; }
    public bool is_known_attacker { get; set; }
    public bool is_known_abuser { get; set; }
    public bool is_threat { get; set; }
    public bool is_bogon { get; set; }
}

public class IP
{
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public bool is_eu { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string region_code { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
    public string country_code { get; set; }
    public string continent_name { get; set; }
    public string continent_code { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public string asn { get; set; }
    public string organisation { get; set; }
    public string postal { get; set; }
    public string calling_code { get; set; }
    public string flag { get; set; }
    public string emoji_flag { get; set; }
    public string emoji_unicode { get; set; }
    public List<Language> languages { get; set; }
    public Currency currency { get; set; }
    public TimeZone time_zone { get; set; }
    public Threat threat { get; set; }
    public string count { get; set; }
}
```

Also I would like to highlight that in case of trying to deserialize the JSON which you've provided above, as `IPList` which should not work.
You might need to use this instead if you want to deserialize that JSON:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IP>(json);
```